# Flink IntervalJoin invoke timestamp

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From Flink docs: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/joining/#interval-join

IntervalJoin will join two streams sharing the same Key and within the lower/upper timestamp boundary,
say I have the following streams

```
packet: [(id=1, ts=20:00:00,...),(id=1,ts=20:00:01,...),(id=3,ts=20:00:02,...),....]
metadata: [(id=1, ts=20:00:03,...),(id=2,ts=20:00:04,...),....]
```

```
packetStream
    .keyBy(elem => elem.id)
    .intervalJoin(metadata.keyBy(elem => elem.id))
    .between(Time.seconds(-2), Time.seconds(1))
```

When will the ProcessFunction be invoked? I understand that it will be invoked twice for id=1 but when? at 20:00:00 and 20:00:01 or only once the window is closed 20:00:03?

Answer (score 1):

The `processElement` method of the `ProcessJoinFunction` is called as each pair of elements becomes available for processing.

In the example you've given, it will never be called for id=1 because there's no metadata event within the specified interval of the events at 20:00:00 and 20:00:01.

Comment: I see, but why for id=1 it won't be called, the window size is 3 seconds where metadata stream 20:00:03 should fit data stream 20:000:01, am I missing something?

Comment: That will only happen if you turn the join around, and join the packetStream to the metadata. As it is, the packetStream at 20:00:01 will join with metadata between 19:59:59 and 20:00:02.